# Get posts which has at least 2 comments on the last 48 hours

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get all posts that has at least 2 comments in the last 48 hours. I'm using the following code:

```
    $posts= Post::has( 'comments', '>', 1 )->whereHas( 'comments', function( $comments ) {
        return $comments->where( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2) );
    })->get()->toArray();
```

1. has at least 2 comments is working fine.
2. in the last 48 hours isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `has()` with `whereHas()` instead of doing that you should only use the `whereHas()` instead.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function($query) {
    $query->where('created_at' ,'>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2))
}, '>', 1)->get();
```

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Comment;

class DemoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function($q) {
            $q->where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-48 hours')));
        })->withCount('comments')->having('comments_count', '>=', 2)->get();

        return view('demo', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe this will help

```
$posts= Post::where( 'comments', '>', 1 )
            ->where( 'comments', function( $comments ) {
                return $comments->where( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2) );
            })
            ->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

Your query is `'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)`

It means `created_at` has been more than 48 hours from today

**But it should be less then 48 hours from today**

So, try this `'created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)`

Comment: Since nobody has told you why they are downvoting (I'm not one) to help you, while this is a bug your correcting it's not the cause of the actual problem, you should probably have commented on this on the question, if you can't comment yet just leave it. don't add answers that are small commentary not direct answers.